# When computing powers of a matrix, is it possible to get different signs?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was using a matrix D that diagonalizes A:

$$D = P^{-1}AP$$

I found it to be $D = \begin{pmatrix}2 &0& 0\\0& -1& 0\\0& 0& -1 \end{pmatrix}$

and the matrix A is $A = \begin{pmatrix}2 &-3& 3\\-3& 2& -3\\-3& 3& -4 \end{pmatrix}$

I needed to compute $A^6$.

So I used $A^6=PD^6P^{-1}$.

I got the same numbers as what $A^6$ would be but my signs were all jumbled up, did i make a mistake?

Comment: I am going to fix some of the LaTex here.  Please have a look at how to make the math more readable.

Comment: Your technique is correct.  You likely made an arithmetic mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got:

$$A^6 = P D^6 P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 & -1\\0 &1&1\\ 1& 0 &1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 &-1 &0\\ 0 & 0 &2 \end{bmatrix}^6 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1&-1&2\\ 1& 0&1\\ -1& 1 & -1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}64 & -63 & 63\\-63 & 64 & -63\\-63 & 63 & -62 \end{bmatrix}$$

Maybe you can show what you have and that will make it easier to see what may have gone wrong as your approach is correct.

For example, did you put your $P$ and $P^{-1}$ in the correct order?